# Laravel class translator does not exist in a configuration file

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-localization

Is there any way that allows inserting translatable value in **configuration file** in **[laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4)** application?

I have a *custom* configuration file at `config/fox-reports.php` and I'm trying to set a translatable configuration value looks like the following:

```
return [
    'attrs' => [
       'Product' => __('Product Title')
    ]
]
```

When I run `php artisan config:cache` the following error is generated:

> **In Container.php line 729:**
>
> ```
>   Class translator does not exist
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `__()` helper in config files because it uses `Translator` class. Laravel loads config at the very beginning of the cycle when most of the services were not initialized yet.

Comment: So there is no way other than translating the value at execution time. i.e from where it called from the application. Something like `__(config('fox-reports')['attrs']['Product']))`

Comment: @SaidbakR keep all translations in language files and in config keep the key that you use in translation file. Then `__(config('fox-reports')['attrs']['Product'])` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness' sake to complement Alexey's answer, translations like this should be handled at a later time. Set up the configuration file with a default value that will be used if no translations exist.

**config/fox-reports.php**

```php
return [
    'attrs' => [
       'Product' => 'Product Title'
    ]
];
```

Then set the translation key up in your [localization JSON files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys), e.g.

**resources/lang/fr/fr.json**

```json
{
    "Product Title": "Titre de produit"
}
```

And in your controller or wherever, you wrap the call to `config()` in the translation function:

```php
// not like this:
// $title = config('foxreports.attrs.Product');
// but like this:
$title = __(config('foxreports.attrs.Product'));
```

If you need to have the default value detected by automated localization tools, just add it to a stub class somewhere, e.g.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Stubs;

class Localization
{
    public method __construct()
    {
        __('Product Title');
    }
}
```